# Unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'list' and 'int'

Tags: python

Before I start, let me just say this is my first time working on a code alone, and I am relatively new to coding. I've only been doing python for a few weeks now.

So I have a school project, and the teacher has let us do whatever we want to do, just that we show we learned something before we move onto the next unit in IT. I'm trying to make a copy of the Oregon Trail, and considering I've resorted to asking the internet it's going less than fantastic (not that the people on this website are less than fantastic). My code currently looks like this:

```
resources = {
  "food": [10],
  "energy": [100],
  "distance": [2000],
  "exhaustion": [0],
  "hunger": [0]

}

def prompt():
    print "You can eat, move, hunt, or rest."

def get_action():
    return raw_input("What will you do?")

def what_do(action):
    for number in resources:
        print number + str(resources[number])
    if action == "eat":
        print "You ate. Hunger restored."
        resources['hunger'] == 0
        resources['food'] -= 1 
    if action == "hunt":
        print "You went out and hunted. You found 10 food."
        resources['food'] += 10 
        print resources['food']
    if action == "move":
        print "You moved 50 miles."
        resources['distance'] -= 50
    if action == "rest":
        print "You rested. Energy restored"
        resources['energy'] == 100
        resources['exhaustion'] == 0

def game():
    while resources['distance'] >= 0:
        prompt()
        action = get_action()
        what_do(action)

game()
```

At the moment the only one action works, and that's the `rest` action. I'm assuming this is because there is no real operator, it's just dropping my exhaustion back to 0. Whether or not it's working as intended, I can't tell because the output remains the same. With every other action, I get a variant of following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 46, in <module>
  File "python", line 44, in game
  File "python", line 27, in what_do
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'list' and 'int'
```

The only things that change from output to output are the third line listed (30 and 34 if you want to know), and the operator changes to a `+`. I'll reiterate that I'm very new to coding, so I don't really know what this means. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the the resources values are stored as a list ie. `"food": [10]` [10] is a list because it's in square brackets. Change resources to this to make it work:

```
resources = {
  "food": 10,
  "energy": 100,
  "distance": 2000,
  "exhaustion": 0,
  "hunger": 0

}
```

Other than that, you need to assign variables using `=` and not `==` since `==` is used for comparing and returns True or False.  So the what_do function should be this:

```
def what_do(action):
    for number in resources:
print number + str(resources[number])
if action == "eat":
    print "You ate. Hunger restored."
    resources['hunger'] = 0
    resources['food'] -= 1 
if action == "hunt":
    print "You went out and hunted. You found 10 food."
    resources['food'] += 10 
    print resources['food']
if action == "move":
    print "You moved 50 miles."
    resources['distance'] -= 50
if action == "rest":
    print "You rested. Energy restored"
    resources['energy'] = 100
    resources['exhaustion'] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

use

resources = {
  "food": 10,
  "energy": 100,
  "distance": 2000,
  "exhaustion": 0,
  "hunger": 0

}

instead

Answer (score 0):

`resources` contains lists as values.

`resources['hunger']` for example returns a list with a single element. What do you expect to happen when you subtract a number from a list?

I don't think you intend `resources` to be a map of lists. Just remove the `[]` from the values in`resources` to make the values numbers instead of lists.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to basically do

```
[2000] - 50
```

Which is not possible because [2000] is a list. Instead of

```
food: [10],
```

Use

```
food: 10,
```

And so on. If you must use lists then do your subtraction like this:

```
resources['distance'][0] -= 50
```

Which accesses the first element of resources['distance'] which is the first element of a list

Answer (score 0):

change resources to

```
resources = {"food":10,"energy":100,"distance:2000,"exhaustion": 0,"hunger":0}
```

and change all of '==' to '=' except those in if statement.

Answer (score -1):

Your initial resources are a diction with `list`s as the values.  You probably want to use just numbers.

```
resources = {
  "food": 10,
  "energy": 100,
  "distance": 2000,
  "exhaustion": 0,
  "hunger": 0
}
```

Next, some of your updates in `what_do` are incorrect.  You should use `=` to update the values of the resources instead of `==` such as:

```
if action == "rest":
    print "You rested. Energy restored"
    resources['energy'] = 100
    resources['exhaustion'] = 0
```